# How to create docker-compose for JIRA and MySQL

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, jira

I'm trying to create a docker-compose.yml file that will bring up JIRA and MySQL. Here's my file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  jira:
    depends_on:
        - mysql
    container_name: jira
    restart: always
    networks:
        - jiranet
    build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile.jira
    environment:
        - ATL_DB_TYPE=mysql
        - ATL_DB_DRIVER=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
        - ATL_JDBC_URL=jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/jiradb
        - ATL_JDBC_USER=jira
        - ATL_JDBC_PASSWORD=jellyfish
    ports:
        - 8080:8080
    volumes:
        - jira-data:/var/atlassian-data/jira

  mysql:
    container_name: mysql
    restart: always
    image: mysql:5.7
    networks:
        - jiranet
    environment:
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=ChangeMe!
        - MYSQL_DATABASE=jiradb
        - MYSQL_USER=jira
        - MYSQL_PASSWORD=jellyfish
    command: [mysqld, --character-set-server=utf8, --collation-server=utf8_bin, --default-storage-engine=INNODB, --max_allowed_packet=256M, --innodb_log_file_size=2GB, --transaction-isolation=READ-COMMITTED, --binlog_format=row]
    volumes:
        - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql

networks:
    jiranet: {}

volumes:
  jira-data:
  mysql-data:
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting JIRA startup errors when it tried to initialize the database, of the form:

```
CREATE command denied to user 'jira'@'172.22.0.3' for table 'jiraaction'
```

I'm guessing it's because the mysql container is creating user jira, but only allowing it to connect from localhost. But, the JIRA container is being seen as coming from an an external IP.

Any ideas on how I can get the jiradb database in mysql to be accessible by the JIRA container by user jira?

Comment: are you able to connect mysql with `jira` user? or did you tried with `root` user?

Comment: I get the same results if i switch ATL_JDBC_USER to root and ATL_JDBC_PASSWORD to ChangeMe. 

If i exec *into* the mysql container, i'm able to connect fine with jiradb or root.

Comment: It is possible that the JIRA container is ready before the DB. (Depends in just controls the order in which the containers start but does not guarantee that a container is ready before the other). Try using the scripts listed on the page below to ensure the DB is ready before JIRA tries to exec commands on it : https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/

Comment: Actually, i had left this detail out, but i was careful to avoid a race condition by first starting the database, then separately starting JIRA after it was all the way up. My guess is that it relates to MySQL's concept of remote user vs local user, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem -- I was missing an environment variable in the jira container:

```
ATL_DB_SCHEMA_NAME=jiradb
```

After that, things worked fine!